# Send two different email messages php

Tags: php, email

I'm looking for a way to send 2 different email messages with different recipients.

I know that I can send the same message to a list of emails, but what I need is to send one text to certain recipients and other text to other list of emails.

I need this because my message contains approval information (which should only be seen by an admin) and I need to sent at the same time other mail just for telling the user *"your request have been sent and will be reviewed".*

Is there a function in `mail()` that can do this?

Comment: can't just use two mail() calls?

Comment: *"Is there a function in mail() that can do this?"* - There sure is, it's called `mail()` and `mail()`

Comment: ^--« I think it's unanimous. ;-)

Comment: Thank you both. I thought the function could be used only once. And Fred it is obvious your answer is unanimous, but I think I need an answer to mark it as good, so for me to give you the recognition you want, I need you to put it as an answer. BTW sorry for my grammar, english is not my native lenguage, neither is php...

Comment: As you wish, but give me time to write up something more proper.

Comment: I've posted my answer for you below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*-As requested-*

Unfortunately, PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function can only handle this by using seperate `mail()` functions.

You can send the same email to multiple recipients at the same time, but to send two different messages (and two different subjects) intended for two different recipients requires using two different `mail()` functions, along with two different sets of recipients/subjects/messages/headers.

For example:

```
/* send to 1st recipient */
$to_1 = "recipient_1@example.com";
$from = "from_recip@example.com";
$subject_1 = "Subject for recipient 1";
$message_1 = "Message to recipient 1";

$headers_1 = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers_1 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers_1 .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";


mail($to_1, $subject_1, $message_1, $headers_1);

/* send to 2nd recipient */
$to_2 = "recipient_2@example.com";
$from = "from_recip@example.com";
$subject_2 = "Subject for recipient 2";
$message_2 = "Message to recipient 2";

$headers_2 = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
$headers_2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers_2 .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";

mail($to_2, $subject_2, $message_2, $headers_2);
```

Comment: I also had this problem but in this way the second mail didnt received, how it works for you?

Comment: what I can do if I have an attachment?

Comment: @AnahitGhazaryan I suggest you "Google" it. There are many good examples out there ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just like this.

```
<?php
//first mail ////
$to      = '1stRe@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = '1st Message';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);



//second mail ////
$to      = '2ndRe@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = '2nd Message';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```